# Has or have with passive voice

Tags: passive-voice

How could I use has/have with passive.

For example,

This has already proofed in 1990.

or

This has already been proofed in 1990.

Which one is correct?

Comment: "This has already been proven." or "This was already proven in 1990". We don't use specific time phrases like "in 1990" with Present Perfect.

Comment: @CowperKettle Thanks a lot. Could you please post it as an answer, this will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"This has already been proven." or "This was already proven in 1990". We don't use specific time phrases like "in 1990" with Present Perfect.

Comment: **Proved** is an alternative past participle to **proven**. Both are correct although idiomatically one or other often works better in particular contexts. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1608/what-is-the-difference-between-proven-and-proved